# KnockoutJS foreach binding add outline around selected items

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have a knockout observable array of items displayed as buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-bind="foreach: myList">
     <button data-bind="css: Sel == false ? 'btn btn-white' : 'btn btn-dark', click:$root.makeChange, text:$data.Id, attr:{'id':'h_'+$data.Id}"></button>
</div>
```

for which I need to add a outline as [image]
for items that have `Sel` set to `true`.

I've tried using `outline: 2px solid black; outline-offset: 1px;` but it adds outline around each button, not for the group and the right line of the outline is drawn behind the next button.

I've also tried using borders, and adding them with JS, but I don't have the space between the button and border.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the original. Sorry for the unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outline` property feels like the right approach to this issue, but it only allows outlining a single element, and it only allows complete outlines.

That means the active elements must be wrapped in a container, and that container must receive the outline.

This can be done with a computed observable that turns a flat list:

```
[
    {text: 'Mon', active: true},
    {text: 'Tue', active: true},
    {text: 'Wed', active: true},
    {text: 'Tue', active: false},
    {text: 'Fri', active: false},
    {text: 'Sat', active: true},
    {text: 'Sun', active: true}
]
```

into a nested one:

```
[
  [
    {text: 'Mon', active: true},
    {text: 'Tue', active: true},
    {text: 'Wed', active: true}
  ],
  [
    {text: 'Tue', active: false},
    {text: 'Fri', active: false},
  ],
  [
    {text: 'Sat', active: true},
    {text: 'Sun', active: true}
  ]
]
```

depending on which item is `active`.

Here is how I would implement that in knockout.

1. A `Button` viewmodel that tracks its own `active` state and allows to toggle it
2. A `ButtonList` viewmodel that contains the buttons and the dynamically calculated `buttonGroups`.
3. A view that creates `.btn-group` and `.btn-group.active` divs based on that.

Interactive sample below:

```js
function Button(params) {
  this.text = params.text;
  this.active = ko.observable(params.active);
  this.toggle = () => this.active(!this.active());
}

function ButtonList(params) {
  this.buttons = ko.observableArray(params.buttons.map(b => new Button(b)));
  this.buttonGroups = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    const groups = [];
    let prev = null, group = null;
    this.buttons().forEach(b => {
      if (b.active() !== prev) {
        group = [];
        groups.push(group);
        prev = b.active();
      }
      group.push(b);
    });
    return groups;
  });
}

const vm = new ButtonList({
  buttons: [
    {text: 'Mon', active: true},
    {text: 'Tue', active: true},
    {text: 'Wed', active: true},
    {text: 'Tue', active: false},
    {text: 'Fri', active: false},
    {text: 'Sat', active: true},
    {text: 'Sun', active: true}
  ]
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.btns {
  display: flex;
}
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
.btn-group.active {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
.btn-group > * {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-group > .active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="btns" data-bind="foreach: buttonGroups">
  <div class="btn-group" data-bind="foreach: $data, css: {active: $data[0].active}">
    <div data-bind="click: toggle, text: text, css: {active: active}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```